# Adding an object to an ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists that hold MusicTrack objects. I want to have an array list for each letter of the alphabet and then within those holds all of the tracks that start with that letter. I am having troubling adding the MusicTrack objects to these inner ArrayLists.

For example: titles[0] holds all tracks that start with A and so on through titles[26] holding Z tracks. The MusicTrack object has a getter method called getTitle() to return the title string for comparison.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TitleBucket implements BucketInterface{
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<MusicTrack>> titles;

    public TitleBucket(){
        this.titles = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MusicTrack>>(26);
        for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
            titles.add(new ArrayList<MusicTrack>());
        }
    }

    public void addItem(MusicTrack itemToAdd){
        int comp = Character.toUpperCase(itemToAdd.getTitle().charAt(0)) - 'A'; 
        // Unsure where to go from here. The above line
        // gets the index of the outer ArrayList but I 
        // don't know how to add it to that ArrayList only
    }
}
```

When I used a for loop it added every track to every single array list so I know it was incorrect, but I don't know what is the right way.

Comment: Since you do letter->list mapping why not use `Map<Character, List<MusicTrack>>`?

Comment: I am new to Java so I'm trying to use ArrayLists to get more comfortable with their functionality. I know this is possible in other ways but I would like to use an ArrayList of ArrayLists as the rest of my files in this directory are dependent on it being set up in this way.

Comment: I would say if you want to learn language then "learn about proper tools it provides for the job (here Map)", but if you want to learn more about algorithms then... maybe start with arrays, they have fixed length which makes things easier. Anyway good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `Map` instead of nested lists. You can use Java Streams to achieve that:

```
Map<Character, List<MusicTrack>> titles = tracks.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(track -> Character.toUpperCase(track.getTitle().charAt(0))));
```

If you want the map to be sorted by key you can use a `TreeMap` for that:

```
Map<Character, List<MusicTrack>> titles = tracks.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(track -> Character.toUpperCase(track.getTitle().charAt(0)), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Finally if you really need to use nested lists you can also transform the map again using `Map.values()`:

```
List<List<MusicTrack>> titles = new ArrayList<>(tracks.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(track -> Character.toUpperCase(track.getTitle().charAt(0)), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .values());
```